# Google Map cannot null exception for MapFragment Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have strictly follow the google map API rules and import the google play service lib as requested. After accidentally updating the google repository and google play service through Android SDK , there are error as follows. What should I do to correct this ? I have privately opened the package of the google play service lib project . it show com.android. UNstubJava which as no other special classes supporting my project.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.larry.proto.maptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission 
        android:name="com.larry.proto.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.larry.proto.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBUHtViyAqpiOofdE0526j4Q-oO9aLut0I" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.larry.proto.maptest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

res/Laylout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Logcat Message

```
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435): Process: com.larry.proto.maptest, PID: 9435
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.larry.proto.maptest/com.larry.proto.maptest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at com.larry.proto.maptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-21 14:31:23.636: E/AndroidRuntime(9435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Code

```
package com.larry.proto.maptest;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener {


    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;

    private GoogleMap myMap;
    Location myLocation;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myMap =  ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                           .getMap();
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    @Override

    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();



        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil

                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());



        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

                    "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)

                    .show();

        } else {

            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,

                    RQS_GooglePlayServices);

        }



    }


    @Override

    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), point.toString(),

                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



    @Override

    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

        .position(point)

        .title("You are here")           

        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));  





        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

                "New marker added@" + point.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)

                .show();



    }



}
```

Comment: What is at line `47`?

Comment: myMap =  ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                           .getMap();

Comment: @RajuGujarati `getMap()` returns null.

Comment: What should I do ? I have already declared this on my Manifest and res/laylout

Comment: <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

Comment: also post your manifest and layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments you have this

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

Should be

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

cause you have

```
 myMap =  ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                       .getMap();
```

`getMap()` returns null.

Intialize GoogleMap object after checking the availability of google play services

> A GoogleMap can only be acquired using getMap() when the underlying
>   maps system is loaded and the underlying view in the fragment exists.
>   This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view;
>   however you cannot be guaranteed when it will be ready because this
>   depends on the availability of the Google Play services APK. If a
>   GoogleMap is not available, getMap() will return null.

Edit:

Looking at the manifest you ahve

```
android:minSdkVersion="14"
```

So change this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

To

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

And revert back to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

Also change this

```
myMap =  ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                   .getMap();
```

to

```
myMap =  ((MapFragment)  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                   .getMap();
```

You don't require the below

```
<permission 
    android:name="com.larry.proto.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.larry.proto.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Initialize GoogleMap object in `onResume`

```
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
       // intialize if success
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `minsdk<12` and/or you want `Backward Compability Support` then

You should change this

```
<fragment xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/map"     
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent"    
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

with

```
<fragment xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/map"     
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent"    
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SuoportMapFragment"/>
```